# Simple audio manipulation library?

Tags: c++, c, audio

I want to make an application that can split an mp3 into pieces. Ex: if I give t a 3 minute song, and want 3 parts, I would expect 3 new mp3s at 1 minute each.

Thanks

Comment: Would you be willing to spawn a program to do it, or do you require a library proper?

Comment: @John whatever can do this as easily as posible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try this: http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/about.php

It claims to have a GUI, and command-line interface, and even a library.  I'd probably start with the GUI or CLI and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Lame should be able to do any basic encoding and decoding you would need.

http://lame.sourceforge.net/